In Azure TestPlans, creating "workstream" which is mandatory inorder to create the test case
In Azure TestPlans, how can I create a Workstream so that it will display in the drop-down option while creating the test case. Please if anyone knows this help me on this.
I tried creating new backlog, feature, in Azure Boards.but I don't think workstream is related to this.

What do you mean about 'Workstream'? Where do you want a drop-down option, and how does the drop-down option look like? Is there any screenshot can show this?
